# Laravel Error On Server for mailer

Tags: php, laravel, mailer

I have tried setting up this project in two different environments and keep getting the same error regardless of PHP version

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class mailer does not exist' in /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:779\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(779): ReflectionClass->__construct('mailer')\n#1 /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(659): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('mailer', Array)\n#2 /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(644): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('mailer', Array)\n#3 /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(890): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('Illuminate\\\\Cont...')\n#4 /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(851): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->reso in /var/www/sos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 779
```

After about 5-6 hours of testing i cannot get this error to go away.

Comment: Please post your code. But first, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no mail notification service is activated (Mail Service)
See:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail
```

Make sure that **`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`** dependency.

After making sure this dependency. After this dependency
Check your .env file for **mail configuration**
check your `config/mail.php`
and finally check `App\Mail\Myfiles.php`
files to make sure of the configuration that your web app support.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply.  i have installed guzzlehttp/guzzle and the same error still occurs.  I hae also checked my config/mail.php and it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check you app.php file for mail service provider `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,` line if not exist then place it and update composer after clear artisan cache.

**UPDATE**
If above detail will not work for you, you need to check your .env file for unwanted space. Some time this error was thrown because one of the values in this file had space. Remove that space and check.

Comment: When i try to clear the cache i get the same ReflectionException that class mailer does not exist.

Comment: @SeanHabing No Worries! Check my update and let me know if still exist.